# What axioms of set theory actually permit me to recursively define things, with complicated recursion properties

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory

Say we want to prove that every Noetherian space is quasi-compact, and we proceed in the following way:

Let $X$ be Noetherian, and let $\underline{U}=\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}$ be an open cover admitting no finite-subcover (for the sake of contradiction).

We can recursively approach this as follows: Take $A_1 = \{U\}$ for some $U\in\underline{U}$. Given $A_n\subseteq \underline{U}$ for which $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq\dots \subseteq A_n$ take an element $x\in X\backslash (\cup A_n)$, i.e. a point in $X$ not covered by $A_n$ (which exists since otherwise there is a finite subcover of $X$ contained in $\underline{U}$). Then pick $L\in\underline{U}$ for which $x\in L$ which is possible since $\underline{U}$ covers $X$ (which may use the axiom of specification? namely to define $\underline{U}_x\subseteq \underline{U}$ consisting of the opens in $\underline{U}$ containing $x$) then (AXIOM I DON'T KNOW) tells us that the recursively defined $\{A_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ satisfy the property that $\cup A_1\subseteq \cup A_2\subseteq \cup A_3\subseteq \dots$ is a non-terminating increasing sequence of open subsets of $X$, contradicting the Noetherian condiction. Hence $X$ is quasi-compact.

Q. What is the (AXIOM I DON'T KNOW)? If you tell me it is the axiom of choice, tell me how you are recursively defining (presumably a modification of $\underline{U}_x$) recursively (without replicating my question lol)?

**Note**: *I don't care about the proof of the actual statement*, I just want to understand how one can recursively define things, conditionally, in potentially complicated ways, from previously built things in the recursion.

No idea what to tag this with, honestly

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate, but there's no particular axiom for this--instead it's a nontrivial theorem that is proved from the axioms.  The idea is to prove by induction on $N\in\mathbb{N}$ that for each $N$ there exists a unique finite sequence $A_1,\dots,A_N$ satisfying the desired recursion, and then take the union of all these finite sequences (using Replacement and Union) to form the infinite sequence.

Comment: (The role of the axiom of choice here is to make the sequences *unique*--you fix a choice function ahead of time which you require to be used to make all of the non-unique choices in the recursion.)

Comment: It's called the Recursion Theorem. The details can be found in any first year set theory textook, like Enderton's. The theorem is certianly nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out, and get back to you both if there are issues.

Comment: In regard to it being a duplicate: if I knew what to search to find a duplicate, I would have also known the answer to my own question.

Comment: @EricWofsey In regard to your first message: I am not sure how I could show there is a unique finite sequence satisfying the condition, since there will be a potentially uncountably infinite collection of choices at each stage (any open in my cover not containing $x$), any of which will do. I could get a unique sequence by adjoining to $A_{n+1}$ every open in $\underline{U}_x$, but this would then defeat the purpose of trying to obtain a finite subcover (not that I am claiming this is what you are suggesting, just noting my confusion in how I would obtain a unique sequence up to $N\in\Bbb N$)

Comment: That's what I mean about the role of the axiom of choice: you fix a choice function ahead of time, and then prove that for each $N$ there is a unique sequence such that all the choices are made using your choice function.